# Python fig.text() - retrieve the height of the text for alignment purposes

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, formatting, figure

so I am writing three different blocks of text to a figure:

The first I would like to write in bold, large white text:

```
texttitle = "My Figure"
fig.text(0.8, 0.8, texttitle, color = 'w', visible = True, linespacing = 2, weight = 'bold', size = 'large')
```

The second in bold, normal white text:

```
letters = "A:\nB:\nC:"
fig.text(0.8, 0.3, letters, color = 'w', visible = True, linespacing = 2, weight = 'bold')
```

And the third in normal red text:

```
numbers = "1\n2\n3"
fig.text(0.9, 0.3, numbers, color = 'r', visible = True, linespacing = 2)
```

Now I current have to call fig.text() three times in order to get different formatting for the different strings, and therefore I have to specify the location of each string making sure they line up so that I get something like this:

[image]

I would like to know is there a way I can do this using just one fig.text() command? 
Or is there a way I can get the dimensions of the other fig.text() calls such that I can line up the next calls to fig.text()?

I am using Mac OSX with the GTKagg backend.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant call is

```
txt.get_window_extent()
```

if `txt` is an Text-object as returned by `plt.text`.

It is important to **draw** the figure before getting the extents, as it is not calculated before. An complete example would be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import offset_copy

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
txt = plt.text(0.1,0.5,"My text", transform = ax.transAxes)

fig.canvas.draw()

text_bbox = txt.get_window_extent()
transform_for_second_text = offset_copy(ax.transAxes, fig, 
                                        x=text_bbox.width,
                                        units="dots")

plt.text(0.1,0.5, "Second text", transform=transform_for_second_text, color="r")

plt.show()
```

resulting in:

[image: Output]

Please note that `fig.canvas.draw()` is an quite expensive operation, so don't do this too often, e.g., first create all white texts, then draw the figure canvas, and then create all red texts.

Comment: One quick question. Here we plot the text at point 0.1,0.5 meaning the  text appears above this point and when we add newlines the text moves upwards. Is there a way to get it so we can specify the point from which the text will write downwards i.e. where the top left of the text is as opposed to the bottom left?

Comment: That's easy (if I didn't misunderstand you). Just control the vertical alignment of the text, use `plt.text(...., va="top")`, leaving the rest of the arguments to `plt.text` as they were.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise the va argument. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to coax such a format by using http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#mathtext-tutorial

You could then create one long latex string that could have different font sizes, etc... I am not sure if you can also control the color.

Comment: Color cannot be controller here- the problem is that matplotlib creates one text from latex and then colors it afterwards, in exactly one color.